# Intellij IDEA overwrites 'i' character with ASCII of 'ı' in gradle-wrapper.properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, character-encoding, gradlew, intellij-idea-2016

There is a weird problem which I am not sure about its source.

I am using Intellij IDEA (2016 3.3) and Gradle (v3.3). I use Windows 10, Turkish OS.

Gradle has a wrapper properties file. (./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)

The content of that file, which is generated by Gradle:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```

When I open a Gradle project in Intellij, the last line of that file turns into this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-b\u0131n.zip
```

Intellij overwrites `bin` into `b\u0131n`. I checked what `\u0131` refers to, and it is ASCII code for 'ı' letter.

And because the URL is broken, I can't build the project.

There are a lot of 'i' letter in that file (not mentioning the whole project), but somehow Intellij turns that specific 'i' in 'bin' into ASCI of 'ı'.

I have this problem for long, but for the first time Intellij insists overwriting it when I try to correct the letter manually. The only difference this time is that I created a multiple-modules containing project which means there are more than one gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Do any of you know why and how to solve this?

Comment: Is "bın" a common Turkish word, and is some kind of spelling correction active?

Comment: @CodeCaster good point but no, 'bın' is not a meaningful word in Turkish. But 'ı' is a Turkish letter.

Comment: I've [reported a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168145) in IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker. It would help if you could attach a sample project to reproduce it. Does it help if you [switch to UTF-8 everywhere](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/)? Does it help if you add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Duser.language=en` into [.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you, I found out this is not an Intellij IDEA's bug but it is Gradle's. Something about locale lowercasing method. I am adding an answer, so others can use this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I found the origin of the bug and it is not Intellij IDEA but Gradle.

```
@Input
    public String getDistributionUrl() {
        if (distributionUrl != null) {
            return distributionUrl;
        } else if (gradleVersion != null) {
            return locator.getDistributionFor(gradleVersion, distributionType.name().toLowerCase()).toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/build-init/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/wrapper/Wrapper.java#L314

toLowerCase() method in here uses my locale (tr-TR) so the output of "BIN".toLowerCase() is "bın".

I added an [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gradle-dev/JHZqo_EJ2zs) in Gradle-dev Google group and suggested a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle, adding;

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.3'
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${gradleVersion}-all.zip"
}
```

solved it for me.

Check [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-wrapper-distributionurl/7116/7) for further info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats not necessary anymore. That bug i mentioned was fixed by me and the fix is included now in the latest version of Gradle.